# need to remove special character from string and space replace with _

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
let updateStreamSelectedCourse = 'mech (electronics)'.replace(/([^\w]+)/g, '_', );
console.log(updateStreamSelectedCourse);
```

output should be mech_electronics

but now im geting output is mech_electronic_

Comment: The question is inconsistent. You say to replace special characters with underscore, but your required output does not do that, it replaces the final special character with nothing. Please give more examples of you can't explain in words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/_$/g,''` should be what you need :

```js
let updateStreamSelectedCourse = 'mech (electronics)'.replace( /([^\w]+)/g, '_', ).replace(/_$/g,'');
console.log(updateStreamSelectedCourse)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace them with different characters, but You can replace the last `_` with the following

```js
let updateStreamSelectedCourse = 'mech (electronics)'.replace( /([^\w]+)/g, '_', ).replace(/_$/,"");
console.log(updateStreamSelectedCourse)
```